# Using echo on data that has an opening quote, but no closing quote

Tags: php, double-quotes

I have a mySQL database.  I am attempting to download one of the tables to Excel.

I am using the basic download PHP:

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.xls");
```

I am then using echo for each field in each row to generate the Excel spreadsheet.

The issue I encountered is that some fields were typed incorrectly, they have their first character as a double quote, with no closing double quote.

This is causing a failure in my code:

```
echo $row['type'] . "\t";
```

As the Excel spreadsheet now merges this cell into all the next--I assume because it sees the opening quote as a beginning quote and doesn't properly end the echo statement.  If I escape the quote, the slash shows in Excel.  What's the fix here?

If the double quote is anywhere else but the first character, I don't have this issue (even a single closing quote).

Answer (score 0):

You could just [trim it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) in php:

```
echo trim($row['type'], '"') . "\t";
```

It will delete any leading and trailing `"` off the string.